# C# How to make an object visible in another class

Tags: c#

Hopefully very simple but I just can't wrap my head around this..

How do I make the object Andrew that I created with the Age class visible outside of the Program class?

The error I get is;
'Andrew.PersonAge does not exist in the current context'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testing2
{
public class Age
{
    private string personage;

    public string PersonAge
    {
        get { return personage; }
        set { personage = value; }
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Age Andrew = new Age();
        Andrew.PersonAge = "30"; 
    }
}


class TestOutput
{
    Console.WriteLine(Andrew.PersonAge);
    Console.ReadLine();    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: you can't make an object visible in another class.

But you can let `Andrew` object be a parameter to pass in the class or `Output` method.

Here is a sample to pass `Andrew` object be constructed parameter, then you can call this class `Output` method to show `Andrew.PersonAge`.

```
public class TestOutput
{
    private Age andrew;
    public TestOutput(Age _andrew)
    {
        andrew = _andrew;
    }

    public void Output()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(andrew.PersonAge);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


Age Andrew = new Age();
Andrew.PersonAge = "30";
TestOutput output = new TestOutput(Andrew);
output.Output();
```

Comment: Thank you this was the answer that worked for me!  (Many thanks for your patient answer, I'm learning so this has helped alot), cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to pass `Andrew` to whatever needs it. Alternatively, you could create a property that exposes it. Your `TestOutput` class won't even compile, so let's add a method that accepts an `Age` object:

```
class TestOutput
{
    public static void Output(Age age)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(age.PersonAge);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Then you just have to call that from `Main()`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Age Andrew = new Age();
    Andrew.PersonAge = "30";
    TestOutput.Output(Andrew);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should refactor your code to replace Age by Person :

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your Program, you need a place to stock your Person and a method to show the result :

```
class Program
{

    public static Person Person { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Person = new Person
        {
            Age = 10,
            Name = "Andrew"
        };

        TestOutput();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to show result
    /// </summary>
    static void TestOutput()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Person.Name);
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried this and even in the method it can't see Andrew.Age ?

        public class Person
        {

            public string Age { get; set; }


        }

        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
               Person Andrew = new Person
               {
                   Age = "30"
               };
                TestOutput();
            }



            static void TestOutput()
            {
               Console.WriteLine(Andrew.Age);
                Console.ReadLine();
           }
       }
   }